# Problem is showing AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'load'?

Tags: python, python-3.7

where should be code changes?My python version is 3.7.4.Here i also have used json.loads(),bt getting a same type of error.
Here is my python code:

```
def get_original_video_paths(root_dir_json,basename=False):
   
    for json_path in glob(root_dir_json):
        with open(json_path, "r") as f:
            metadata = json.load(f)
```

Showing a error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-625a577bf289> in <module>
     49     json='F:/deepfake_data/metadata/metadata.json'
     50     data_folder='F:/deepfake_data/train_sample_videos_2'
---> 51     ids = get_original_video_paths(json)
     52     #ids = get_original_video_paths(json)
     53 

<ipython-input-41-a0214372cfb6> in get_original_video_paths(root_dir_json, basename)
     17         dir = Path(json_path)
     18         with open(json_path, "r") as f:
---> 19             metadata = json.load(f)
     20 
     21         for k, v in metadata.items():

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'load'
```

passing a file path:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    json='F:/deepfake_data/metadata/metadata.json'
    #data_folder='F:/deepfake_data/train_sample_videos_2'
    ids = get_original_video_paths(json)
```

Comment: You can't reassign a string to `json` and still expect to have access to the `json` module

Comment: @DeepSpace now ,where i can change my code?

Comment: Since the problem is that you reassign to `json`, try not to. `path = 'F:/deepfake_data/metadata/metadata.json'`

Comment: @DeepSpace ,i also try this way,bt a got same error.ids = get_original_video_paths('F:/deepfake_data/metadata/metadata.json')

Answer (score 0):

Restating what @DeepSpace commented, the problem is with the line just before you called `get_original_video_paths`:

```
json='F:/deepfake_data/metadata/metadata.json'
```

The `json` variable is providing access to the `json` module, and by making the variable reference the path to your metadata file, none of your code can access the `json` module and its functions.

```
    with open(json_path, "r") as f:
--->    metadata = json.load(f)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'load'
```

The error message, `'str' object has no attribute 'load'`, is saying that it looked at what the `json` variable is referencing, got your string (`str`) showing the path to the file, and tried looking for a method called `load` in your string.

#### Solution

The simple way to fix it is to not name variables the same as imported modules. For example, you could call the path to your metadata file "path" or "metadata":

```
metadata = 'F:/deepfake_data/metadata/metadata.json'
data_folder = 'F:/deepfake_data/train_sample_videos_2'
ids = get_original_video_paths(metadata)
```